# Moment.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defineLocale' of undefined at moment.js:13

Tags: javascript, momentjs, libraries

When running the small html file below I see the following console log error:

```
moment.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defineLocale' of undefined
    at moment.js:13
    at moment.js:9
    at moment.js:10
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>

    <script src="../scripts/libraries/moment.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<script>
  var now = moment()
  console.log(now);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried replacing the reference to the local library with this CDN link: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/locale/af.js`

Anyone know what this error is?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your version of `moment.js`. The script that you have is only for `locale`, you need to include the `moment.js` script:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var now = moment()
    console.log(typeof moment.defineLocale)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If it was an incorrect path, OP would have gotten a "moment is not defined" error

Comment: you saved my day !!! all the paths that I got include local at the end...weird !!!
Thanks

Comment: _ no problem! _

Answer (score 4):

This error also occurs when you include locale js prior to moment js.

For instance following gives error:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/locale/tr.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

To correct, just put moment js above to locale js.